# Ubuntu crashes during installation on ACER laptop

Tags: acer, system-installation

I just bought an Accer Aspire E1-522 with windows 8.1

- Processor: AMD A6-5200 APU with Radeon(TM) HD Graphics 2.00Ghz
- 12 GB RAM

I boot the disk, It starts installing Ubuntu but it blanks and stops running

[This is](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BAQjEl-0-Gc) what happens.

Please help me with this to install Ubuntu, may be there is a bug for this computer, or some thing to make it work, but I don't know how.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also installing ubuntu on an acer aspire e1-522, full ubuntu install not a dual boot and had similar problems. Here is what I have done.
On boot press <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Go to security and disable Secure boot (note you may have to enter a user password first to disable secure boot) you also need to enable the <kbd>F12</kbd> select boot device option

Insert your usb stick or CD and select that device to boot after <kbd>F12</kbd>

When the boot menu comes up press <kbd>E</kbd> to edit the boot options and in  the line that starts with linux type `nomodeset` after quiet splash, this will allow you to boot with basic graphics.

note after you reboot your system when the install finished you can press the escape button to get you to the grub menu (just press it a few times so you see the menu and don't end up with just the grub prompt) from the menu select recovery mode and then fail safe graphics.

Then follow the instructions for loading the [catalyst drivers](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Catalyst-Linux-Installer-Notes.aspx) and [BinaryDriverHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD).
Note go to section 3.2 not section 3.1 (assuming you have a Radeon HD 8330)
in a terminal you can type `lspci` to see which graphics card you have.

I am still have problems with the ACPI but that is for later
Good luck.

Comment: I am glad to know someone with an accer 522 that whants to install ubuntu.

Comment: when you say that you dont whant to install dual boot, does that mean that you are erasing windows 8? I dont whant to erase win8.1,I have done a partition in the disc to install ubuntu, does this mean that I cannot use what you wrote up here?

Comment: I did erase the entire windows 8 since the dual boot was too difficult, however I ran the acer backup onto a usb stick and this let me recover the entire system. I am actually back on windows 8 now since I needed ms office for work purposes. I think I will wait for a few months until ubuntu catches up the new hardware in the e1-522, I have run ubuntu on slightly older laptops and it works without any problems but I had too many problems on the E1-522

Comment: when I ran the safe graphics, it gives an error, and sends me to the same window. Is this normal?   [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fkTbW9Lkp5Q&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Hi! I´m going to install the radeon catalyst drivers, but I´m not shure which ones I have to choose to download. I know that I have de amd radeon hd 8400, but where I should choose product, only appears  radeon 8xxxM  and my series isn´t M, will this one work on my aspire, or should I choose another one?, which series did you choose so it could work on your asus? Thanks a lor, you are being wery helpfull